# jQuery Tablesorter custom parser, sorting dates with default `-` when no date available

Tags: date, tablesorter

I have written custom parser to sort on dates in format: 23-jul-2014

```
        $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'dates',
        is: function(s, table, cell) {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {

            // capture groups for rearranging
            pattern = /(^\d{2})-([A-Z]{3})-(\d{4})/gi;
            parts = pattern.exec(s);

            date = parts[2]+" "+parts[1]+", "+parts[3];
            return date ? $.tablesorter.formatFloat((new Date(date).getTime() || ''), table) || s : s;
        },

        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'numeric'
        });
```

,but in some of my fields where date is missing, I have `-` literally.

When this occurs sorting stops working, because it does not recognize that as
regex match.

How would I change my parser code, so that it still can sort on that column,
just by ignoring such fields having `-`, and sorting on those which have the
proper date as `23-jul-2014`?

I tried replacing that last `s` in `return date...` statement, to something
like `1-jan-1970` to provide default value for `-` fields, but that didn't
help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't necessary to split out all the parts of the date. Just replacing the dash with a space will work ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3584/)):

```
$(function () {
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'dates',
        is: function (s, table, cell) {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected
            return false;
        },
        format: function (s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
            var date = new Date(s.replace(/-/g, ' '));
            return $.type(date) === 'date' ? $.tablesorter.formatFloat(date.getTime(), table) || s : s;
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'numeric'
    });

    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra']
        // add headers option here or "sorter-dates" class to header
        // ,headers : { 6 : { sorter: 'dates' } }
    });
});
```

---

Update (from question in comment):

The `|| s : s` is code that has two different things going on.

The first part `|| s` really isn't necessary in this case since the `formatFloat` function will return the same value if it is not numeric. The two vertical bars mean "OR", so `0 || 'x'` will result in `'x'`. So when javascript encounters an "OR" `this || that` if the left part is determined to be "falsy" (has a value of `undefined`, `null`, an empty string or has a value of zero), it is replaced with the value on the right side.

The second part is the ending of a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). Basically the format is:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false;
```

so in the above the function

```
return $.type(date) === 'date' ? $.tablesorter.formatFloat(date.getTime(), table) || s : s;
```

we are returning a ternary operator (only the condition matching part is returned):

- The `condition` is `$.type(date) === 'date'`, to make sure we have a date object
- The `value_if_true` part is `$.tablesorter.formatFloat(date.getTime(), table) || s`
- The `value_if_false` part is `s`

The ternary operators can be nested and can be very confusing to read, so use them, but don't go nuts ;)

Comment: Will this work properly when some of the fields have literal `-`, instead of date? So no date at all available in such field?

Comment: I will accept your answer, just can't do it now from mobile, there is some bug in app for stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you explain that `... ||s : s` logic?

Comment: I am aware of the ternary operator, what I don't understand is, if `s` cannot be parsed as date, in both cases it will return original string so why ternary operator is used here?

Comment: Sure, it can be rewritten as `return $.type(date) === 'date' && $.tablesorter.formatFloat(date.getTime(), table) || s;`, it works either way.